# identifier new is undefained

Tags: c, poo

He empezado recientemente con C y estoy con los punteros. Intentando crear una matriz dinámica con un objeto que yo mismo creé no para de salirme el error "identifier new is undefained" cuando inicializo tablero.

```
#include "tablero.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "objetos.h"

objeto_t** reservaTablero(int numFilas, int numColumnas){
 //declarar un puntero doble de objeto_t llamado tablero
 objeto_t **tablero;
 //iniciar la primera dimensión del puntero doble “tablero” con un array de numFilas de 
 //punteros a objeto_t
 tablero = new objeto_t*[numFilas];
 
 //por cada fila del tablero
 //inicializar esa fila del tablero con un array de objeto_t de tamaño “numColumnas
 for (int i = 0; i < numFilas; i++)
 {
    tablero[i]=new objeto_t[numColumnas];
 }
 
 //devolver el array doble tablero
 return tablero;
}
```

La clase tablero.h es la siguiente:

```
#ifndef __TABLERO_H__
#define __TABLERO_H__
#include "tipos.h"

#define NFILAS 20
#define NCOLUMNAS 10

void iniciaTablero(objeto_t tablero[NFILAS][NCOLUMNAS], int numFilas, int numColumnas);
void dibujaTablero(objeto_t tablero[NFILAS][NCOLUMNAS], int numFilas, int numColumnas);
objeto_t** reservaTablero(int numFilas, int numColumnas);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los operadores `new` y `delete` son propios de C++.

En C tienes [`malloc`, `free`, `calloc` y `realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory). La mayor parte del tiempo usarás los 2 primeros, menos frecuentemente el tercero y probablemente nunca `realloc`.

- `malloc` reserva memoria pasándole la cantidad de bytes como parámetro.
- `calloc` también. A diferencia de `malloc`, permite inicializar la memoria reservada al valor que quieras. Como primer parámetro recibe dicho valor y como segundo parámetro la cantidad de bytes.
- `free` libera la memoria pasándole un puntero con la posición de memoria a liberar.
- `realloc` permite cambiar el tamaño de memoria ya reservada. El primer parámetro es un puntero con la posición de memoria y el segundo el nuevo tamaño.

Tu código se vería así:

```
objeto_t** reservaTablero(int numFilas, int numColumnas) {

    tablero = malloc(sizeof(objeto_t*) * numFilas);

    for (int i = 0; i < numFilas; i++)
    {
        tablero[i] = malloc(sizeof(objeto_t) * numColumnas);
    }

    return tablero;
}
```

---

Cabe mencionar que C es un lenguaje de paradigma imperativo y estructurado. Por lo que no hay POO. Nada de clases ni objetos.

Tampoco tiene referencias, templates y por ende STL tampoco.

Te dejo una buena referencia de C, con todas las funciones que provee la librería estándar: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c

Comment: Muchas gracias :D